# React post request with jwt bearer id_token returns 401 but it works with same token in postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authorization, fetch, identityserver4

I'm trying to post an image to my API.
Logging in works great and authentication works on that part.
Then when I try to authenticate for the POST request, using JWT bearer token that's returned from my identity server I get a `401 unauthorized`.

Using the same `id_token` in postman and posting the same image works and gives me a ``200 success` along with storing the posted image.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm setting up the `fetch`?

```
 const data = new FormData()
        console.log(user)
        event.preventDefault()
        data.append("file", image, user.profile.unique_name.slice + ".png")
        fetch(devUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.id_token}`
            },
            body: data
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    setSuccessUpload(true)
                }
            })
```

UPDATE:
I'm incompetent and it turns out I was using `id_token` and not `access_token` like you should..

Comment: You mean Access Token? The id token can't be used to access resources.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg OMG I can't believe I've been sitting for hours and using id_token instead of access.... Thank you it's working now haha!